# How to make a chessboard pattern with a nested loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested

I need to make a pattern that looks like this:

1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0

0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1

1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0

0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1

1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0

0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1

1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0

0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1

So far, I've only been able to make a diagonal with the ones, but I need some help understanding how to get to this.

My code so far:

```
dimension = int(input('Enter dimension of board: '))

if dimension < 2:    
    print('Invalid input')    
else:
    for r in range(dimension):
        for c in range(dimension):
            print(int(c == r), end=' ')
        print()
```

Answer (score 2):

`(c + r + 1) % 2` should work instead of `int(c==r)`.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you where you want to be.

```
for r in range(dimension):
    for c in range(dimension):
        print(int((c + r + 1) % 2), end=' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the desired board output you're looking for:

```
def printBoard(dimensions):
    for row in range(dimensions**2):
        if row % dimensions == 0 and row != 0:
            print()
            print((row + 1) % 2, end=' ')
        else:
            print((row + 1) % 2, end=' ')
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly when `dimensions` is even: all rows start with '1'.

Answer (score 0):

```
#List comprehension can be used here.
def print_board():
    n=int(input('Enter dimension of board: '))
    row=[[(x+1)%2 for x in range(n)], [x%2 for x in range(n)]] 
    board=[row[x%2] for x in range(n)]  
    for r in board:
        for c in r: print(c, end=' ')
        print(' ')
```

Comment: This works, although it makes the top left corner '0' rather than '1'.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variant of balabhi's technique. It uses a nested list comprehension to construct the even and odd rows, and it then uses the `str.join` method to join the cells of each row into a string. The `make_board` function returns a list of row strings, which are joined into a single string for printing using another `.join` call.

```
def make_board(side):
    r = range(side)
    rows = [' '.join(['01'[(i + p) % 2] for i in r]) for p in (1, 0)]
    return [rows[i % 2] for i in r]

# Test
for i in range(0, 9):
    board = make_board(i)
    print('{0}:\n{1}\n'.format(i, '\n'.join(board)))
```

**output**

```
0:


1:
1

2:
1 0
0 1

3:
1 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 1

4:
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1

5:
1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1

6:
1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1

7:
1 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1 0 1

8:
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

i know, it's maybe a little bit late, but here is a very general and at the same time fast solution:

```
  1 import numpy as np
  2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  3 import time
  4 from PIL import Image
  5 import os
  6
  7 def divmod_max_into(div_mod):
  8     if div_mod[1] > 0:
  9         return div_mod[0] + 1
 10     else:
 11         return div_mod[0]
 12 def create_chessboard(dim_x, dim_y, cube_size):
 13     start = time.time()
 14     light_grey = 230
 15     dark_grey = 90
 16     divmod_x_cube = divmod(dim_x, cube_size*2)
 17     divmod_y_cube = divmod(dim_y, cube_size*2)
 18     large_cube = np.full([cube_size*2, cube_size*2], False)
 19     large_cube[:cube_size, :cube_size] = True
 20     large_output = np.tile(large_cube, (divmod_max_into(divmod_x_cube), divmod_max_into(divmod_y_cube)))
 21     large_output = np.transpose(large_output) + large_output == 2
 23     output = np.full(large_output.shape, dark_grey, dtype=np.uint8)
 24     output[large_output] = 230
 25     print("Execution took {:.6f} seconds!".format(time.time()-start))
 26     return output[:dim_x, :dim_y]
 27
 28 Image.fromarray(create_chessboard(5000, 5000, 3)).save(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'out.tif'))
```

You can also define the size of the cube, that should be repeated. Creating an 5000x5000 array takes about 0.74 seconds on my PC.

If something is unclear, feel free to ask.